# Concatenate multiple rows of hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

***Ticket:***

```
id_ticket |id_ticket_category |
----------|-------------------|
1         |8                  |
2         |8                  |
3         |13                 |
```

***Category:***

```
id_category |id_parent |label                             |id_category_type |
------------|----------|----------------------------------|-----------------|
1           |-1        |Demande d'information             |1                |
2           |-1        |Réclamation                       |1                |
3           |1         |Autre                             |2                |
4           |1         |Mairie                            |2                |
5           |1         |Stationnement                     |2                |
6           |2         |Autre                             |2                |
8           |3         |Autre                             |3                |
9           |4         |Réservation de salle              |3                |
10          |4         |Autre                             |3                |
11          |5         |Horaires de stationnement         |3                |
12          |5         |Autre                             |3                |
13          |6         |Autre                             |3                |
16          |7         |Autre                             |3                |
```

Notice that the `id_ticket_category` column in the `Ticket` table refers to the `id_category` in the `Category` table.

I want to return the count and `concat` row who i have a `id_ticket_category (id_category)` with id_parentof element.

***Example:***

For the `id_ticket_category = 8` i look on the `Category` table

```
id_category |id_parent |label                             |id_category_type |
------------|----------|----------------------------------|-----------------|
8           |3         |Autre                             |3                |
```

I look is `id_parent` is not equal at `-1`

```
id_category |id_parent |label                             |id_category_type |
------------|----------|----------------------------------|-----------------|
3           |1         |Autre                             |2                |
```

I look is id_parent is not equal at -1

```
id_category |id_parent |label                             |id_category_type |
------------|----------|----------------------------------|-----------------|
1           |-1        |Demande d'information             |1                |
```

`id_parent` is equal `-1` i print my result

```
Category                 |count|
-------------------------|-----|
Autre-Demande Information| 2   |
```

Actually i have this request:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.label, '-', parents.label), c.id_parent  
FROM Category c INNER JOIN
(SELECT id_category AS id, label FROM category c WHERE id_parent = -1) AS parents
ON parents.id = c.id_parent 
WHERE  c.id_category_type < 3 
ORDER BY c.id_category_type;
```

so does anyone know how to improve this?

Comment: Are you set on using MySQL? I'm asking because other RDBMS have recursive properties for exactly what you need.

Comment: @KindaTechy yes i using MySQL

Comment: Is there a limit on depth? If max depth is known the solution is simple.

Comment: @SalmanA the limit is knowing `c.id_category_type < 3`

Comment: @Mercer your structure allows unlimited depth... I am asking if it is OK to hardcode, for example 3, as the maximum depth? Also, are you OK with alternate tree structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: What does "improve this" mean? What is your question?

Comment: thx bro for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to group tickets by category and display the count and the *path*. This works if category tree is maximum 3 level deep:

```
SELECT
    id_ticket_category,
    CONCAT_WS(' > ', c3.label, c2.label, c1.label) AS `category`,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN category c1 ON ticket.id_ticket_category = c1.id_category
LEFT JOIN category c2 ON c1.id_parent = c2.id_category
LEFT JOIN category c3 ON c2.id_parent = c3.id_category
GROUP BY id_ticket_category, category
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+
| id_ticket_category | category                              | count |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+
|                  8 | Demande d'information > Autre > Autre |     2 |
|                 13 | Réclamation > Autre > Autre           |     1 |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+
```

---

**Converting to Nested Set Model**

The [nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is more efficient at retrieving hierarchical data. However, maintaining it could be difficult. If you are interested then you first need to transform your data into this:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+------------------+------+------+
| id_category | id_parent | label                     | id_category_type | l    | r    |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+------------------+------+------+
|           1 |        -1 | Demande d'information     |                1 |    2 |   19 |
|           2 |        -1 | Réclamation               |                1 |   20 |   25 |
|           3 |         1 | Autre                     |                2 |    3 |    6 |
|           4 |         1 | Mairie                    |                2 |    7 |   12 |
|           5 |         1 | Stationnement             |                2 |   13 |   18 |
|           6 |         2 | Autre                     |                2 |   21 |   24 |
|           8 |         3 | Autre                     |                3 |    4 |    5 |
|           9 |         4 | Réservation de salle      |                3 |    8 |    9 |
|          10 |         4 | Autre                     |                3 |   10 |   11 |
|          11 |         5 | Horaires de stationnement |                3 |   14 |   15 |
|          12 |         5 | Autre                     |                3 |   16 |   17 |
|          13 |         6 | Autre                     |                3 |   22 |   23 |
|          16 |         7 | Autre                     |             NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+------------------+------+------+
```

Then you can use this query (which has no limit on depth of category tree):

```
SELECT
    id_ticket_category,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(parent.label, ' (', parent.id_category, ')') ORDER BY parent.l SEPARATOR ' > ') AS category,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id_ticket) AS `count`
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN category ON ticket.id_ticket_category = category.id_category
LEFT JOIN category parent ON category.l BETWEEN parent.l AND parent.r
GROUP BY id_ticket_category
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------+
| id_ticket_category | category                                          | count |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------+
|                  8 | Demande d'information (1) > Autre (3) > Autre (8) |     2 |
|                 13 | Réclamation (2) > Autre (6) > Autre (13)          |     1 |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: it's work if category tree is maximum n level deep ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is sort of hard-coded. If your data is maximum 4 level deep then you need another `LEFT JOIN category c4 ON c3.id_parent = c4.id_category` and so on.

Comment: There is another solution but it requires you change your data structure. That should not be a problem but the new fields need to be updated every time a category is added/removed, and that could be a pain-in-the-bottom if using SQL.

Comment: I can not make disappear  the `id_ticket_category `column disappear from the output result i have an error

Comment: @Mercer I made small changes to the `GROUP BY` clause in the query. Now you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the following prcedure to perform the task,

Following is the Procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getConcatRows;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getConcatRows(IN id_tc int)
 BEGIN

 DECLARE id_parent_tc int;
 SET id_parent_tc = id_tc;

 DROP temporary table IF EXISTS temp_category;

 # Create temporarty table to store hirarchy
 create TEMPORARY table temp_category 
 AS 
 select 0 as id_category,category.label,-1 as id_tc from category limit 1;


 WHILE id_parent_tc <> -1 
 DO
   insert into temp_category select id_category,label,id_tc from category WHERE id_category=id_parent_tc;

   SELECT id_parent into id_parent_tc FROM category WHERE id_category=id_parent_tc;
 END WHILE;

 # Subtract 1 since it will contain the total herarchy
 select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct label),count(1)-1 from temp_category t where t.id_tc = id_tc group by id_tc;
 END //

 DELIMITER ;

 CALL getConcatRows(8);
 # Will return the required output
```